# Nav Panel sticking problem to top of screen

Tags: html, css

Here is a snippet of HTML and CSS code of a web site that I'm working on. I can't get the nav panel to stick to the top of the screen when scrolled. The idea is, when the logo section (which has a height of 210px) scrolls out of sight, the nav panel sticks to the top of the screen. I lack the knowledge of how to do this, and for some reason, tutorials on the internet that show how to do this, fail in my project. PS.this is a school project so go easy:D

CSS code snippet:

```css
#logo
{

 width:auto;
 height:210px;
 text-align:center;
 padding-top:10px;
 border-bottom:4px solid #088A08;
 background-color:rgba(0, 255, 64, 0.8);
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
#all
{
 height:700px;
}
#content_container
{
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 width:auto;
 background-color:red;
}
#nav
{
 height:auto;
 background-color:rgba(0, 255, 64, 0.8);
 margin-top:25px;
 margin-left:25px;
 width:10%;
 padding: 10px;
 border:4px solid #088A08;
 border-radius:10px;
 opacity:8; 
 float:left;
}
.nav_button
{
 border:2px solid #088A08;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 border-radius:10px;
 padding:3px;
 width:auto;
}


HTML code snippet:
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </div>
  <div id="all">
    <div id="content_container">
      <div id="nav">
        <b>
  Spis Treści:
  <a href="#podstawy"><div class="nav_button">Podstawy</div></a>
  <a href="#obrazy"><div class="nav_button">Wstawianie Obrazków</div></a>
  <a href="#tabele"><div class="nav_button">Wszystko o Tabeli</div></a>
  <a href="#listy"><div class="nav_button">Rodzaje List</div></a>
  <a href="#edycja"><div class="nav_button">Edytowanie Tekstu</div></a>
  <a href="#tlo"><div class="nav_button">Tło, Kolor</div></a>
  <a href="#uk"><div class="nav_button">Uwagi Końcowe</div></a>
  </b>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at the css propetry  `position: sticky;`

Answer (score 0):

You made a little bit of a mess with your code.
Remember to always close every tag you open.
Also you need to know a little bit of javascript to make it work.
A nice example from a good site i learned a lot from is

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

The javascript code is explained in the page but i'm gonna explain it a little bit

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("nav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

First of all the script check when the user scroll the page and then it fire a function when it happens.

Then it calculate the offset (the distance) of the navbar from the top.

Finally the function itself, fired when the user scroll the page.
If the user scrolls the same distance then the offset (=>), then it apply the class sticky to the navbar, else it removes it.

I put all together [here](https://codepen.io/uitta/pen/yxdwQv).